# Can I borrow 15 bits for specific netmask in class B

Tags: ip, subnet, ip-address

I read that I can't borrow 15 bits to create a specific netmask from a default class B netmask.
According to my calculation, borrowing 15 bits gives :
specific netmask = 255.255.255.254

Why did they say this is impossible ?

Comment: /15 bitmask is 255.254.0.0. I don't understand the rest of your question.

Comment: Classful networking is dead, killed over 20 years ago by RFCs 1518 and 1519. Please, let it rest in peace. Seriously, modern network equipment does classless routing.

Answer (score 1):

RFC 3021 describes using 31-bit prefixes for point-to-point links. This leaves 1 bit for the host-id portion of the IP address. Normally a host-id of all zeros is used to represent the network or subnet, and a host-id of all ones is used to represent a directed broadcast. Using 31-Bit prefixes, the host-id of 0 represents one host, and a host-id of 1 represents the other host of a point-to-point link.

Local link (limited) broadcasts (255.255.255.255) can still be used with 31-bit prefixes. But directed broadcasts are not possible to a 31-bit prefix. This is not really a problem because most routing protocols use multicast, limited broadcasts, or unicasts.

For more information look at the [Cisco Documentation](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/dynamic-address-allocation-resolution/13711-40.html).

Answer (score 0):

11111111.11111111.11111111.1111111**0**  --> Network ID

11111111.11111111.11111111.1111111**1**  --> Only available host ID **BUT** it's an all 1's host ID therefore a broadcast

Conclusion : No actual machine ID will be usable here hence a /31 is not possible if we want to do networking with client machines

Thanks Flippy